# Heroku can not compile Symfony2.7 project

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, heroku-postgres, symfony-2.7

I need your help with a problem using a symfony2.7 upload on heroku. I entered the command `git push heroku master` this is the error: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BztswIqNuWoTQjA4enJzelM0dlU/view

Comment: So why don't disable Doctrine bundle at all?

Comment: Hello @eRIZ,  I'm Sorry , If I just use for login